# how do i reduce the loading time of a pre-trained model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, resnet, transfer-learning

While loading the weights of "Imagenet" using ResNet50 it nearly takes 10-11sec each time while loading the weights.
Is there any way to reduces the loading time ?

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from flask import request,Flask
import json
import os
import time

from keras.preprocessing import image as image_util 
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
# from keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/object_rec', methods=['POST'])
def object_rec():

      f = request.files['file']
      file_path = ("./upload/"+secure_filename(f.filename))
      f.save(file_path)
      image = image_util.load_img(file_path,target_size=(299,299))
      image = image_util.img_to_array(image)
      image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=0) #(224,224,3) --> (1,224,224,3)
      image = preprocess_input(image)

      start_time = time.time()
      model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet")
      pred = model.predict(image)
      p = decode_predictions(pred)

      ans = p[0][0]
      acc = ans[2]
      acc = str(acc)
      if ans[1] == "Granny_Smith":
            ans = ans[1]
            ans = 'Apple'
      else:
            ans = ans[1]
      print("THE PREDICTED IMAGE IS: "+ans)
      print("THE ACCURACY IS: "+acc)
      print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
      result = {
            "status": True,
            "object": ans,
            "score":acc
      }
      result = json.dumps(result)
      return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=6000,debug=True)
```

time taken would differ between 8-11 sec.
I would be good if it loads the model in 3-4sec and does classification.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should instantiate the model outside of your function so that it is only loaded once. ~10s is not a surprising time for big models like ResNet.

Comment: Yeah, But calling the model outside the function won't work. I'm actually converting the code into API using flask, So when I instantiate the model loading outside the function would give me tensor error.

Comment: I updated the answer based on a tf+Flask bug found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287)

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do it, is to load the model in a specific session and then every time you want to use the model just set that specific session, then just call predict where you need it:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# IMPORTANT: models have to be loaded AFTER SETTING THE SESSION for keras! 
# Otherwise, their weights will be unavailable in the threads after the 
session there has been set
set_session(sess)

model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet")

@app.route('/object_rec', methods=['POST'])
def object_rec():
   global sess
   global graph
   with graph.as_default():
      set_session(sess)
      model.predict(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=6000,debug=True)
```

Comment: Doing this give me a error : ValueError: Tensor Tensor("fc1000/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

And this get_model() would re-load each time again when I call it inside object_rec().

Comment: you don't load it inside object_req, you load it outside just like I wrote it. To solve the issue try app.run(..., threaded= False)

Comment: i get the same error : ValueError: Tensor Tensor("fc1000/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Comment: Still the same error : ValueError: Tensor Tensor("fc1000/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Comment: are you developing, deploying? it depends on what configuration you are using, look at [this](https://github.com/jrosebr1/simple-keras-rest-api/issues/1)

Comment: Let me explain what I'm doing. I have created a Resnet layer using transfer learning. This script is then converted to API using a flask so that this API can be called in a mobile application to detect a fruit !

Comment: I get this error after including the tensorflow graph : NameError: name 'graph' is not defined